# "msg":"Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I'm using node and mongoose to update a watson rank and retrieve database. I'm trying to add documents to the collection. I can add a single document. However, the json object I'm creating for multiple is failing. I've seen this answer here, but it was for curl. I was wondering if someone can help me with the JS part.

```
    // add a document
    //var doc = { id : 1234, title_t : 'Hello', text_field_s: 'some text' };
    var data = [];

    for (var count = 0; count < documents.length ; count++){
        data.push({"add":{"doc":{id : documents[count]._id, problem : documents[count].problem, description : documents[count].description, resolution : documents[count].resolution}}})
    }

    console.log(data);

    solrClient.add(data, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log('Error indexing document: ' + err);
      } else {
        console.log('Indexed a document.');
        solrClient.commit(function(err) {
          if(err) {
            console.log('Error committing change: ' + err);
          } else {
            console.log('Successfully commited changes.');
            callback(documents);
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

I get this:

```
[ { add: { doc: [Object] } },
  { add: { doc: [Object] } },
  { add: { doc: [Object] } },
  { add: { doc: [Object] } },
  { add: { doc: [Object] } },
  { add: { doc: [Object] } } ]
```

However, I think I need this:
[ add: {doc: [Object] },
add : {doc: [Object] },
...

When I try to remove the { in front of the add, I get an error (missing ) after argument list) and it won't run.

Comment: Well, `[ add: { doc: ...` wouldn't be valid anything. I don't know the API; does it want a collection of `{ add: { doc: ...}}` or does it want a collection to add like `{ add: [ { doc: ...}, { doc: ...} ]}`? What do the docs say?

Comment: The example has: {
  "add" : {
    "doc" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "author" : "brenckman,m.",
      "bibliography" : "j. ae. scs. 25, 1958, 324.",
      "body" : "exnt .",
      "title" : "experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a wing in a slipstream ."
    }
  },
  "add" : {
    "doc" : {
      "id" : 2,
      "author" : "ting-yili",
      "bibliography" : "department of aeronautical engineering, rensselaer polytechnic institute troy, n.y.",
      "body" : "simple flow .",
      "title" : "simple s incompressible fluid ."
    }
  },

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the test code](https://github.com/pabloviquez/node-solr/blob/36aae73dbed0ba4c9a9ef1b046ca2c8f96ebeddd/test/test-update-array.js#L12-L23), I think that you need to use a simple array of document objects:

```
var data = [];

for (var count = 0; count < documents.length ; count++){
  data.push({ id : documents[count]._id, problem : documents[count].problem, description : documents[count].description, resolution : documents[count].resolution})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ 
    add: {doc: [Object] },
    add : {doc: [Object] },
    //...
    add : {doc: [Object] }
]
```

is a associative array, which is translated in JS as a object.
And a object can't have multiple property named the same.

What you probably need however, is a simple arra:

```
[
    {doc: [Object] },
    {doc: [Object] },
    //...
    {doc: [Object] }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[ add: {doc: [Object] }, add : {doc: [Object] }, ...` is invalid because the keys are not unique.

<s>And your code is correct I think. Just change like this `callback(null, documents);`</s>

I think `callback` is for your upper method.

So you don't have `callback` in you question sample code.

You do not need to call `commit`. Just adding is enough.

```
solrClient.add(data, function(err, added) {
      if(err) {
        console.log('Error indexing document: ' + err);
      } else {
        console.log('Indexed a document.');  
        console.log(added);      
      }
    });
```

Comment: I made the change, but I still get the same error. Also, the keys I'm getting are from a Mongoose database, so they are unique.